# Merge array by value of a value cell (no doubles)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, array-push

I was wondering if it's possible to merge an array by a value of a cell (no doubles) right of the php box.

To clarify this is my current array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 90
            [Name] => David,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 90
            [Name] => Eric,
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 77
            [Name] => Eva,
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 77
            [Name] => Gila,
        )

)
```

So we have:

2 persons (David and Eric) that have the same score (90)
2 persons (Eva and Gila) that have the same score (77)

So by the end of the day (in that case) I want to get only 2 rows (merged by score) and the names will be added to the same line that merged by score.

This is what I'm expecting to get :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 90
            [Name] => David,Eric,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Score] => 77
            [Name] => Eva,Gila,
        )

)
```

Here is my php code :

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:text/plain");

$myArray=array();

$myArray[]=array('Score'=>'90','Name'=>'David,');
$myArray[]=array('Score'=>'90','Name'=>'Eric,');
$myArray[]=array('Score'=>'77','Name'=>'Eva,');
$myArray[]=array('Score'=>'77','Name'=>'Gila,');

print_r($myArray);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure it is possible – but please show us some code. SO is for helping you with code problems, not to provide you with code.

Comment: @Markus my code is pretty easy in that case so I thought it would be negligible in that case :)

Comment: It never is. It shows a lot. Please _edit_ your question accordingly.

Comment: that's how you create your data structure. Show us what you have tried to get to the wanted result, please. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Hey @Markus I tried many thing and it wasn't helpful for that task... I know that it is possible and I can solve it but I asked about a magic right out the box php 1 single line that will do the trick for me :) Hope it make more seance...